# Changing CSS display properties with jquery

Tags: jquery

This code allows me to hover over a div with class "steps-hover" and change from display: none (in my stylesheet) to display: block. Works perfect. But what if I want to change the display of a different class while hovering? That's where I am confused.

Ultimately I want to hover over the div "steps-hover", still retain the same results below but also change the css of a different div with class "default" to be display: none. Here is my current code:

```
function over(event) {
$('.steps-hover', this).stop(true, true, true).fadeIn(500);
$('.steps-hover', this).css("display", "normal");
}

function out(event) {
$('.steps-hover', this).stop(true, true, true).fadeOut(500);
}
```

So how do I add the changes to .default in there? I tried a couple different things, but no luck. My assumptions must be way off and I can't find the answer in the jquery API documentation. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use too:

```
function over(event) {
$('.steps-hover', this).stop(true, true, true).fadeIn(500);
$('.default').hide();
}

function out(event) {
$('.steps-hover', this).stop(true, true, true).fadeOut(500);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! And I used $('.default').show(); on the out event to make it show up again. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `over` function, why not do:

```
$(".default").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: Perfect! I tried this before, but retained the .this in there like the previous line so it wasn't working. Now I need it to return to display block on mouse out. I tried $(".default").css("display", "normal"); , but not working.

Comment: @user2574250 -- `$(".default").css("display", "block");` for the mouse out :)